# How does a router settings page work?

Tags: router

When we enter the routers address 192.168.x.x into our browser we get a page containing the setting for the router. How does this page work ? Is the page stored in the router ?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 2):

Yes the router has a small web server that is used to manage it.